# Do all C++ compilers generate C code?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

Probably a pretty vague and broad question, but do all C++ compilers compile code into C first before compiling them into machine code?

Comment: @tyler "Cfront was the original compiler for C++ (then known as "C with Classes") from around 1983, which converted C++ to C"

Comment: We could even extend the answer from "not all compilers do it" to "no compiler does it".

Comment: Well, some higher level languages compile from $language into C. Possibly ML?

Comment: maybe only if if you explicitly tell so using extern "C" :)

Comment: @GManNickG: Comeau appears to be dead now. The site hasn't been updated in 4 years.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because C compilers are nearly ubiquitous and available on nearly every platform, a lot of (compiled) languages go through this phase in their development to bootstrap the process.

In the early phases of language development to see if the language is feasible the easiest way to get a working compiler out is to build a compiler that converts your language to C then let the native C compiler build the actual binary.

The trouble with this is that language specific constructs are lost and thus potential opportunities for optimization may be missed thus most languages in phase two get their own dedicated compiler `front end` that understands language specific constructs and can thus provide optimization strategies based on these constructs.

C++ has gone through phase 1 and phase 2 over two decades ago. So it is easy to find a `front end' of a compiler that is dedicated to C++ and generates an intermediate format that is passed directly to a backed. But you can still find versions of C++ that are translated into C (as an intermediate format) before being compiled.

Comment: These days with free portable optimizing back-ends like LLVM available, it's also common for new compilers / languages to start out as front-ends that feed LLVM-IR to the LLVM libraries for optimization and code-gen to any target it supports.

Comment: @PeterCordes backend like LLVM have always been around. I was using GCC IL graph format back in 95/96. But even with this being available and easy to use C++ first version was implemented with a translation to C (back in 83 IL was still around). The jump from a translator to generating a backend specific intermediate format is still large, so writing a translator to C is an easy way to test things out. If you still see promise in the language then using LLVM backend is a good next step.

Answer (score 14):

Nope.  GCC for example goes from C++ -> assembler.  You can see this by using the `-S` option with g++.

Actually, now that I think about it, I don't think *any* modern compiler goes to C before ASM.

Comment: Comeau compiles C++ into C. (Which then goes on to be compiled into a binary.)

Comment: @GMan Wow!  I've never heard of the Comeau, and you just gave me a very good reason to keep it that way!

Comment: @Gianni: Actually Comeau is regarded as one of the most compliant compilers around. :) (That's all I know though; not a clue on how well it actually produces optimized binaries.)

Comment: Though you are correct about g++ (not GCC) you cant tell that because of the -S option. Before it reaches assembly the code is actually translated through several intermediate formats (most of which can be dumped to file).

Comment: In fact, Comeau's **C compiler**  uses C as its intermediate represenation, too. Pretty much every compiler does a front-end translation into some intermediate representation - Comeau's intermediate representation happens to be C, which means he doesn't need to maintain a backend for each of the platforms he supports. Since he's a one-man shop (I think), that makes a certain amount of sense. I suppose he could have used whatever intermediate representation that GCC uses, but there might be licensing or other issues that made that less desirable.

Answer (score 8):

No.  C++ -> C was used only in the earliest phases of C++'s development and evolution.  Most C++ compilers today compile directly to assembler or machine code.  Borland C++ compiles directly to machine code, for example.

Answer (score 4):

No. **This is a myth**, based around the fact that a very early version of Stroustrup's work was implemented that way. C++ compilers generate machine code in almost exactly the same way that C compilers do.

As of this writing in 2010, the only C++ compiler that I was aware of that created C code was [Comeau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comeau_C/C%2B%2B)<sup>*</sup>. However, that compiler hasn't been heard from in over 5 years now (2022). There may be one or two more for embedded targets, but it is certainly not a mainstream thing.

---

<sup>* - There's a link to their old website on this WP page. I'd suggest not clicking that unless your computer has all its shots up to date</sup>

Answer (score -2):

This is not defined by the standard. Certainly, compiling to C-source is a reasonable way to do it. It only requires the destination platform to have a C-compiler with a reasonable degree of compliance, so it is a highly portable way of doing things.
The downside is speed. Probably compilation speed and perhaps also execution speed (due to loads of casts for e.g. virtual functions that prevents the compiler to optimise fully) will suffer.
Not that long ago there was a company that had a very nice C++ compiler doing exactly that. Unfortunately, I do not remember the name of the company and a short google did not bring the name back. The owner of the company was an active participant in the ISO C++ committee and you could test your code directly on the homepage, which also had some quite decent ressources about C++.
Edit: one of my fellow posters just reminded me. I was talking about Comeau, of course.

Comment: I think you're thinking of Comeau. It was already mentioned in another answer posted nearly four years ago.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I asked this question almost 4 years ago :). 

Your answer is not really adding anything to this thread.

Comment: The difference between you mentioning Comeau, and everyone else mentioning it: You did it a year after it was dead.