# C code not working

Tags: c, linux

I have this C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ) {
    char Username[100];
    char Password[100];
    printf("discl0sed 0.1 discl0sed tty1\ndiscl0sed login: ");
    scanf("%s", Username);
    printf("Password: ");
    scanf("%s", Password);
    if (Username == "root" && Password == "!DISCL0SEDor1=1--")
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            printf("Login incorrect\ndiscl0sed login: ");
            scanf("%s", Username);
            printf("Password: ");
            scanf("%s", Password);
            printf("%s:%s", Username, Password);
            if (Username == "root" && Password == "!DISCL0SEDor1=1--")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which mirrors a `tty` shell in Linux.
The problem is when I use the correct credentials, it says "Incorrect login".

Why does this happen?

Comment: Look up `strcmp` - Google it!

Comment: when looking at the manual page for that - read about `scanf`

Comment: Please turn your compilers warnings on!

Comment: They are on, but there was no warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will help,

In C, you have to compare the string by using strcmp or strncmp. It is like a String.Equal in Java.

If you are comparing int which in the stack memory it is okay because it's written (in the memory) as itself, but if the variable is in the allocated memory or array each element has address of the contents which in the allocated memory. Since two addresses of the contents are different, you have to compare the contents itself by using functions.

Good Luck !

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. C++ one would use `std::string`

Comment: In C you would use `str*cmp()` but in `C++` you would use `std::string::compare`.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi OMG.. You're toally right !! It was a quite long time ago.

Comment: @Kwang-ChunKang - Never make a claim that you cannot support. Compilers don't convert C++ to C. There are some compilers that will convert C++ to C http://geneura.ugr.es/~jmerelo/c++-faq/convert-to-c.html that some use when native C++ compiler doesn't exist.

Comment: "But, in my opinion, C++ convert it's code to C internally" - 1) That does not matter. You can convert Lisp to C, too, but that does not make them the same or even similar language. Every program is eventually translated to machine code. Does that make all languages the same? 2) Welcome past the 1980ies.

Comment: @alvits You're totally right; and I've heard that long time ago and believed without doubt. It's my mistake. Please understand I deleted my wrong comments and I surrender !!! OTL....

Comment: @Olaf I got it and C/C++ are different. You're right. ! and thank you for welcoming... haha ;;;

Comment: @All For who will find the comment, My apolgoies for deleteing the previous comment; I admit that C/C++ are different unlike I commended those are similar/same; and I had out-dated information and C++ internally converted into C. Hope it will helps for others.

Comment: @All For who will find the comment, for more details of the Is C++ converts to C, please refer [C++ISCONVERTINGTOC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311563/do-all-c-compilers-generate-c-code)